# unable to run gs-rest-service-initial from STS

Tags: spring, rest

I am using STS 3.8.3. When I tried to run the sample gs-rest-service-initial using Spring Boot App option, I do not get any output in the console except the below:

Can any one please suggest where is it going wrong:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.1.RELEASE)

[2017-02-17 12:54:07.073] - 12600 WARN [main] --- org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ParameterMessageInterpolator: HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
[2017-02-17 12:54:07.195] - 12600 WARN [main] --- org.hibernate.validator.messageinterpolation.ParameterMessageInterpolator: HV000184: ParameterMessageInterpolator has been chosen, EL interpolation will not be supported
```

Comment: Please provide some code. Start with Application.java and explain what is STS and how you include it.

Answer (score 0):

Add slf4j-simple jar in your classpath.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you, Not only slf4j, I had to add several different jars. Basically I tried to resolve all the warnings and it started working :-)